# Adding background-color on TD made my border disappear

Tags: html, css

This is how it looked like after adding `background-color`

[image]

For this table , the CSS involved are :

```
    .styleTable td,th
{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:10pt;
}


.tdColorGrey
{
    background-color:#B8B8B8 ;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px;
}
```

and this is my table style:

```
 <table class="styleTable" style="width: 80%;background-color:white;" border="1">
```

The borders appear without `tdColorGrey` but they disappear once i added it.

Comment: Post a complete code example please, not just the CSS and one line of HTML. You can even create a stack snippet right in your question as a live example.

Comment: does `border:1px solid black;` change anything?

Comment: You may missing a border style, just like `border: solid 1px;`. But as j08691 said, some more code would be nice.

Comment: Add a style for your Border like style="border: 1px solid #000;"

Comment: the border fixed it. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that

```css
border:1px;
```

is a *shorthand* property, which literally means

```css
border-width:1px; border-style:none; border-color:currentColor;
```

See [description on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border).
So if you assign the class to any `td`, it will have a border-style of none instead of inheriting from the table.

So possible solutions, as mentioned in the comments, are

- write the style explicitly in the css:

  ```css
  border:1px solid black;
  ```

  (whatever style and color you need, that is)
- or, remove the `border` property from the css altogether, so that the border will inherit normally!